# c:forEach + Data table multiple row selection crashes old selected values

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i use JSF 2.0 and primefaces 4.0

my JSF code :

```
 <c:forEach items="#{materielbean.materielist}" var="list" >
        <p:dataTable  var="car" value="#{materielbean.listeitemsmaterielbyidmateriel(list.idmateriel)}" rowKey="#{car.iditemsmateriel}"  
                 selection="#{fournisseurbean.selectedItemsMateriel}" selectionMode="multiple" style="width : 664px; ">  
        <f:facet name="header">  
          #{list.nommateriel} 
        </f:facet>          


        <p:column headerText="designation">  
            #{car.designation}  
        </p:column>  
        <p:column headerText="Unité">  
            #{car.unite}  
        </p:column>   


    </p:dataTable> 

     </c:forEach>
```

and the used function

```
listeitemsmaterielbyidmateriel(list.idmateriel)
```

is defined like this

```
public List listeitemsmaterielbyidmateriel(int i){
return  itemmaterielDAO.DisplayItemsMaterielDAOselonmMateriel(i);
}
```

And finally this is the DAO code

```
public  List DisplayItemsMaterielDAOselonmMateriel(int idmateriel )
    {

        Query q = em.createQuery("select LIM from ItemsMateriel LIM inner join LIM.materiel where LIM.materiel.idmateriel= :idmateriel");
        q.setParameter("idmateriel", idmateriel);
        List l = new ArrayList();
        l= q.getResultList();

        return l ;
    }
```

when i run this code , i got no errors , but  `selection="#fournisseurbean.selectedItemsMateriel}"`
 returns only the values of the final iteration(final datatable) , it's because in every iteration the list crashes old selected objects and put new selected objects , how can i do to prevent this ??

Comment: It is a known issue, but it was fixed recently for MyFaces 2.2.x. See: [MYFACES-3811](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3811) for details. You could try if the [latest snapshot](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/myfaces/core/) and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well sorry for late , but i discovored that the solution is easier than i thought :
First create a new list

```
List<ItemsMateriel> Tampon = new ArrayList<ItemsMateriel>();
```

Second modify the setter to :

```
public void setSelectedItemsMateriel(List<ItemsMateriel> selectedItemsMateriel) {               
        Tampon.addAll(selectedItemsMateriel);
        this.selectedItemsMateriel = selectedItemsMateriel;         
    }
```

And finally to use the new list (Tampon) and you'll find all selected objects

Answer (score 2):

It's dangerous to mix JSTL core tags with JSF- and/or *Faces tags. Basically JSTL tag handler get executed during view build time, while JSF UIComponents get executed during view render time. See the very good answer at ["JSTL in JSF2 Facelets… makes sense?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3343681/1269441)

Have you already tried to solve the issue using Facelets `ui:repeat` component?